# Is this a Non-homogeneous DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is this a Non-homogeneous DE because the term $12t$ does not contain the independent variable or any of its derivatives?

$$\frac{dy}{dt}+6yt=12t$$

Comment: What was the definition of a homogeneous differential equation you learned?

Comment: I forgot, that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: One says that a first order linear differential equation $\tfrac{dy}{dt} = f(t, y)$ is linear, if $f$ has the form $a(t)y + b(t)$, and one says that this linear differential equation is homogeneous if $f$ has the form $a(t)y$ (so $b = 0$). In your example $f(t, y) = 12 - 6ty$, so $a(t) = -6t$ and $b(t) = 12t$. The equation is linear but not homogeneous. The associated homogeneous differential equation is $\tfrac{d}{dt} = -6ty$, and there is a general method for solving the equation that proceeds by first solving the associated homogeneous equation.

Answer (score 0):

first step solve the equation $$\frac{dy}{dt}+6y(t)t=0$$
and after this get a special solution of the inhomogeneous equation

Comment: The review task came out with a vote of 5-2 in favor of deleting this. That is a borderline vote in my book, because I cannot rule out votes out of inertia. If there were accompanying downvotes, I might think differently. Apparently the reviewers didn't feel strongly enough about this case.